# Fixing a loop to continue with the program instead asking the same thing again in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with this dice game. When I try to make it skip to the next piece of code, it just goes back. Please help:

```
import random  # Importing the module

decision = ('y')  # Setting variable 'decision' as y
roll_number = 1  # Setting variable 'rolling_number' as 1

name = input('What is your name?\n')  # Setting a variable as a condition so that the User can change the variable. It is an input.

while decision == ('y'):  # While loop for the decision
    if roll_number > 1:  # If loop for roll_number
        same_person = input('\nAre you the same person? If so please press y, if not please press n. Pressing anything else ask your name again!\n') #Asking if the User is the same person
        if same_person == ('y'):  # If it is the same person
            print('Okay!')  # Outputs 'Okay!'
            continue  # Skips to the next part of the code
        else:  # Otherwise
            name = input('\nWhat is your name?\n')#Asks name again

    number = random.randint(1,6)  # Generates random number between 1 and 6
    ready = input('\nPress any button to roll the die!\n')  # Lets the user know when it's ready
    print('Rolling...\n'*4)  # Output Rolling... 4 times 
    print(name,'! Your die shows a ',number,'!\n')  # Outputs the name and the number
    roll_number = roll_number+1  # Adds 1 to the variable 'roll_number'
    decision = input('Do you want to try again? If so please press y, if not please press n. Pressing anything else will stop the program!\n')  # Letting the User change the variable so they can use the program

else:  # Otherwise
    print('Bye!')  # Outputs 'Bye!'
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`continue` only skips the rest of the body of the loop, it does not *exit* the loop. As such, when `same_person == 'y'` is true, you send Python back up to `while decision == 'y'` (note, the parenthesis around `'y'` are entirely redundant here and can be omitted).

Use `break` to exit the loop. The `else` statement at the end of the loop will then *not* be executed, you may want to remove `else:` there and un-indent the `print('Bye!')` line.